# Given a string containing just parentheses, determine if the input string is valid

Tags: javascript, programming-challenge, functional-programming, ecmascript-6, balanced-delimiters

**The task**
is taken from [leetcode](https://leetcode.com/problems/valid-parentheses/)

> Given a string containing just the characters '(', ')', '{', '}', '['
>   and ']', determine if the input string is valid.
>
> An input string is valid if:
>
> - Open brackets must be closed by the same type of brackets.
> - Open brackets must be closed in the correct order.
> - Note that an empty string is also considered valid.
>
> **Example 1:**
>
> ```
> Input: "()"
>
> Output: true
> ```
>
> **Example 2:**
>
> ```
> Input: "()[]{}"
>
> Output: true
> ```
>
> **Example 3:**
>
> ```
> Input: "(]"
>
> Output: false
> ```
>
> **Example 4:**
>
> ```
> Input: "([)]"
>
> Output: false
> ```
>
> **Example 5:**
>
> ```
> Input: "{[]}"
>
> Output: true
> ```

**My functional solution**

```
/**
 * @param {string} s
 * @return {boolean}
 */
var isValid = s => {
  const par = {
      "(": ")",
      "{": "}",
      "[": "]",
    };
  const rep = [];
  return [...s].every(x => par[x] 
                      ? rep.push(par[x])
                      : rep.pop() === x) && !rep.length;
};
```

**My imperative soltion**

```
/**
 * @param {string} s
 * @return {boolean}
 */
var isValid2 = s => {
  const par = {
      "(": ")",
      "{": "}",
      "[": "]",
    };
  const rep = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
    if (par[s[i]]) {
      rep.push(par[s[i]]);
    } else {
      if (rep.pop() !== s[i]) {
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
  return rep.length === 0;
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code looks quite succinct and sufficient. The only suggestions I would offer are minor tweaks:

- for the imperative solution, a `for...of` loop could be used to eliminate the need to do bookkeeping on the counter variable and use it to index into the string to get each character:

  ```
  for(const c of s) {
    if (par[c]) {
      rep.push(par[c]);
    } else {
    if (rep.pop() !== c) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  ```
- for the functional solution, the callback function could be declared on a previous line, and then the `return` line can be reduced to a single line:

  ```
  const pushOrPopMatch = x => par[x] ? rep.push(par[x]) : rep.pop() === x
  return [...s].every(pushOrPopMatch) && !rep.length;
  ```

  That line defining `pushOrPopMatch()` is 73 characters long, which some might argue is too long for a line, given it would be inside a function and indented at least two spaces, so it may not be ideal